# How to mock or spy on recaptcha in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, recaptcha, angular-test

I added `recaptcha-v2` in my `Angular6` forms. How do I `unit-test` the form? I want to test that the `form` under test is invalid if `recaptcha` isn't clicked and also the form gets submitted if `recaptcha` is clicked.

The test I have written so far is

```
  fit('it should emit form values if both username and password fields in the login form are correctly filled', () => {
    const loginComponent = component;
    spyOn(loginComponent.formOutputEvent, 'emit');
    const formControls = loginComponent.loginForm.controls;
    const email = 'test@test.com';
    const password = 'testpassword';
    formControls['userName'].setValue(email);
    formControls['password'].setValue(password);
    formControls['recaptcha'].setValue({}); //what value to set here?
    loginComponent.loginFormSubmitted();
    expect(loginComponent.formOutputEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new LoginFormValues(email, password));
  });
```

I am getting error `Expected spy emit to have been called with [ LoginFormValues({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'testpassword', recaptcha: '' }) ] but actual calls were [ LoginFormValues({ username: 'test@test.com', password: 'testpassword', recaptcha: Object({  }) }) ].`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, the following works even though `LoginFormValues` expects the 3rd argument to be of type `string` but `{}` isn't

```
expect(loginComponent.formOutputEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new LoginFormValues(email, password,{}));
```

But this fails because `{}.toString()`. gets converted to `[Object object]`.

```
expect(loginComponent.formOutputEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new LoginFormValues(email, password,{}.toString));
```

I am still waiting for better answer